# Linear Algebra matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A and B are 3x3 matrices such that $A^{2}=A$ and $B^{T}=B^{-1}$. Then show that,
$A^{6}-AB(A^{T}B)^{T}=0$

work:
$A^{6}-AB(A^{T}B)^{T}$

$A^{6}-AB(B^{T}(A^{T})^{T})$

$A^{6}-AB(B^{T}A)$

$A^6-ABB^{-1}A$

$A^3-A^2$

Not sure where  I am going wrong.

Comment: Prove that $A^n=A$, for $n>1$.

Comment: Agree with egreg, this will help ( and be enough ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems, both minor. First, there should be en equals sign between every pair of things you've written. Second, at the last step, you have
$$
A^3 - A^2 = A( A^2 - A) = A (0)
$$
because from $A^2 = A$ we know that $A^2 - A = 0$. Thus your complete solution looks like this:
\begin{align}
A^{6}-AB(A^{T}B)^{T} 
&= A^{6}-AB(B^{T}(A^{T})^{T}) \\
&=A^{6}-AB(B^{T}A)\\
&=A^6-ABB^{-1}A & \text{because we know $B^T = B^{-1}$}\\
&=A^3-A^2\\
&= A(A^2 - A) \\
&= A ( 0 ) & \text{because $A^2 = A$ means that $A^2 - A = 0$}\\
&= A.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Premultiply by $A$ repeatedly in $A^2=A$ to get $A^6=A$. Also $AB(A^TB)^T=AB(B^TA)=ABB^{-1}A=A^2=A.$ Hence $A^6-AB(A^TB)^T=A-A=0$